# C# mp4 stream continuous without server manipulation?

Tags: c#, stream, mp4

I"m trying to consume an mp4 stream in C# (WPF) direct from sources without any server/mid software to convert. The stream is continuous. No control or audio are necessary, just the constant video stream.

media element & embedded web browser controls with some added codecs tried but no luck.

just want a simple, continuous mp4 stream. Once working, application will read many streams simultaneously for multiple source monitoring without any control or audio of media so a rolled class is an option if a simple stream converter/consumer isn't available.

any assistance is appreciated - thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion: See if you can get such streams played back with the (standalone) VLC media player. If it does, you might want to look into using [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet), which can embed VLC capabilities into a WPF UI; (before going all-in, you should make a quick test WPF application to see if it is suitable for having multiple such VLC players at once in a simple test UI, playing different streams)

Comment: thanks. great suggestion. I'll try that. appreciate it. will let you know any progress /nick